# Do Sifrei Torah use kashida justification?

Tags: sefer-torah, safrus

During aliyah, I noticed that the certain letters in the Sefer Torah  what appeared to me to be kashida justification. From Wikipedia:

> Kashida or Kasheeda (Persian: کشیده; "extended", "stretched", "lengthened") is a type of justification in the Arabic language and in some descendant cursive scripts. In contrast to white-space justification, which increases the length of a line of text by expanding spaces between words or individual letters, kasheeda creates justification by elongating characters at certain points.

Is what I saw a form of justification, or something else?

Comment: Cool word! Thanks